Macro that prints an integer in Mars (a IDE for MIPS assembly language)
I'm new to MARS and using macros for my simple program. Reading Mars help, in Macros tab, there's example state that macro "Printing an integer (argument may be either an immediate value or register name)". So why the argument accepts both an immediate value and reg name, whereas
add $a0, $0, %x is used??? (%x is a argument)
While using that macro, i see that MARS compiles the macro with immediate argument by addi, whereas add was used, is something that i need to find out or just accept that is how MARS work :))
